# "void promiseExpression" in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, react-native

Looking at a React Native app in TypeScript, and there is this fragment in a screen file:

```
export const DetailPageScreen: FC<StackScreenProps<AuthorizedNavigatorParamList, 'Details'>> = observer(({ route, navigation }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    void (async () => {
      await SomeFunction();
    })();
  }, []);
```

Help me parse what goes into `useEffect`. It's a function with a body that goes:

```
() =>
{
    void (async () => {
      await SomeFunction();
    })();
}
```

So what's inside the parentheses after `void` is an async function invocation without an `await` - an expression that results in a promise, I presume. So what is `void` doing here, exactly? It boils down to `void promiseObject`, if I followed this right.

Comment: This is (most likely) used to surpress warnings by linters, see e.g.: https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-floating-promises/#ignorevoid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So what is void doing here, exactly?

At runtime, nothing. The [`void` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) simply evaluates what's in front of it and returns `undefined`.

Without additional context, my best guess is that this is a hint to some linter, most likely [`typescript-eslint`](https://typescript-eslint.io/) with the [`no-floating-promises`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-floating-promises) rule.